Enigmatic Puzzle 4: Three Leaf Clover
Asking for some help as I've created puzzles for a new book and now am looking for them to be tested (and to get some feedback for improvements). On Sunday, I'll be posting the puzzles I think are the most challenging yet, so stay tuned.
Hints provided if you ask.

Three Leaf Clover
    I'm not sure if I go before or after you
Start
High
Rope
Daily
Stunt
Team
Saw
Prince
Fire


Thanks for the helpful tips! I'll do my best to include just text anytime a puzzle is, in fact, just text. I'll also be sure to not use that tag unless I'm in the process of creating a puzzle.

The final word is

 TRIPLE

If you

 Find a word which can go before or after each word for each of the groups of 3 to make a phrase you get:


JUMP START, HIGH JUMP, JUMP ROPE
 DAILY DOUBLE, STUNT DOUBLE, DOUBLE TEAM
CROWN SAW, CROWN PRINCE, CROWN FIRE

Then if you

 Take each word JUMP, DOUBLE, CROWN
 You can place TRIPLE next to each to make the phrases:
TRIPLE JUMP, TRIPLE DOUBLE, TRIPLE CROWN


Terrific! Hope you enjoyed the puzzle.

Yes it was fun! I am looking forward to the harder puzzles tomorrow. You don’t have to post them all at once- spacing them out would be preferable.
